# Rear ABS Sensors Peugeot 307

Tags: sensor, peugeot, abs

I have a Peugeot 307 and the passenger side ABS sensor had recorded a fault (after an expensive Diagnostics) so I replaced both rear sensors now there is an ABS fault on both rear wheels communication error.

***The garage that has done the DIAG for me said it could be the wheel bearings but if there was no fault on the drivers side and there now this would point to a Sensor Fault, would it not?***

The garage wants to charge me £220 to replace bearings.  I'm of the beleif that they don't need to.  Would you all agree?

**Is there any known problem with spurious ABS sensors on Peugeot 307's?**

ABS Sensor : http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/252177475774

Comment: I have no idea how wheel bearings could give a communication error on a sensor...  But maybe I'm not reading it the right way.

Comment: yeah i thought this, but there little bar like sensors that slip behind the disk on this car so if bearing is causing movement against the sensor perhapse it's possible

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever solve this problem?

I have just had a customer buy some eBay Peugeot ABS sensors and they were completely faulty.

Replaced with some OE quality (Pagid) sensors and the car was fine.

I would suggest only using OE quality part or at least only buy parts from a decent motor factors.

Comment: About 2 weeks after this post the Engine Management light came on and that was the last straw i scrapped the car not wasting more than the car cost me on repairs in the first year :)